# Как получить позицию элемента?

Tags: xpath

```
<td><div>текст1</div><div>текст2</div><div>текст3</div></td>
```

что-то наподобие `//*[text()[contains(.,"текст2")]]/position()` # должно быть 2 - возможно ли как-нибудь вернуть позицию элемента ?

Comment: Скорей всего — нет т.к. `xpath` для этого не предназначен: на выходе у него всегда элементы синтаксического дерева xml...

Comment: @Fat-Zer - При использование count на выходе обычно число ... Ни соглашусь с вами ..

Comment: гмм... резонно... но всё равно не уверен, на сколько такое использование корректно — надо будет спецификацию на досуге посмотреть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count(//div[text()="текст2"]/preceding-sibling::*) + number(boolean(//div[text()="текст2"]))
```

Или подсчитывайте позицию элемента средствами языка, если функция count() не работает.